# make mp=((c ^ ((p+1)/4)) mod p) in php?

Tags: php, algebra

I want to make mp=(  C^((p+1)/4) mod p ) in php

```
function truemod($num, $mod) {
  return ($mod + ($num % $mod)) % $mod;
}

$mp= truemod(exp(((($p+1)/4))*log($c)) , $p);
$mq= truemod(exp(((($q+1)/4))*log($c)) , $q);

echo "Nilai mp :  $mp <br>";
echo "Nilai mq :  $mq <br>";
```

when i use that script , i got 0 when the value of c/p/q are big , any solution ? 
what should i put in $mp for get C^((p+1)/4) mod p ?

i try to change

```
$mq= truemod(pow($c,(($q+1)/4)),$q);
```

it still same

any suggestion for that operation? thanks

Answer (score 0):

the variables overflow... use a bigint library to handle arbitrary big integers...

http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger

Comment: And use sprintf to display large number as string

Answer (score 0):

(2025^60) mod 239 ,

when i use http://web2.0calc.com/ and modulo calculator from http://www.calculatorpro.com/calculator/modulo-calculator/

i get (2429414689006507011047680668198610544614376056243160093821961151708217872022541081600097552192834563575596196518385368260399467853246465311637303360756939677768395657864175518625415861606597900390625) mod 239

2429414689006507011047680668198610544614376056243160093821961151708217872022541081600097552192834563575596196518385368260399467853246465311637303360756939677768395657864175518625415861606597900390625 mod 239 is 45.00 .

but when i use Math_bigInteger

```
$a = new Math_BigInteger(239);
$b = new Math_BigInteger(2025);
$c = new Math_BigInteger(60);

echo $a->powMod($b, $c);
```

I got 59

Which one is correct ??